# Copying XML content between 2 tags from one file to another

Tags: shell-script, sed, grep, xml

I have got 2 XML files.

1.xml

```
<abc>
....
....
</abc>

<xyz attrib1='1234'>
...
...
</xyz>
```

2.xml

```
<abc>
xxx
xxx
</abc>
<xyz attrib2='4321'>
xxx
xxxx
</xyz>
```

I need to use shell scripting to replace the content of 'xyz' tag in file 1.xml by the content in 2.xml to give me final file like:

```
<abc>
    ....
    ....
    </abc>
    <xyz attrib2='4321'>
    xxx
    xxxx
    </xyz>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/<xyz[ >]/,/<\/xyz>/p' 2.xml | \
sed '/<xyz[ >]/,/<\/xyz>/ { /<\/xyz>/! d; r /dev/stdin
    D; }' 1.xml >output.xml
```

Please note that there must be a newline after `/dev/stdin`.

Another way with `sed`, cleaner but less efficient:

```
{
    sed '/<xyz[ >]/,$d' 1.xml
    sed -n '/<xyz[ >]/,/<\/xyz>/p' 2.xml
    sed '1,/<\/xyz>/d' 1.xml
} >output.xml
```

Comment: Trying it in a single `sed` also works, but made it ugly for me: `sed -n "H;1h;\${g;s/\n/<<>>/g;s/<xyz .*xyz>\(.*\)<abc.*\(<xyz .*xyz>\).*/\2\1/;s/<<>>/\n/g;p}" 1.xml 2.xml`.

Comment: @Philippos That potentially reads a lot of stuff in memory, but I suppose it's still a valid answer.

Comment: did not work. It does not replace the complete <xyz> tag with the content of 2.xml. It just grabs the content of 2.xml between the tags and prints it

Comment: @AbhishekKothari Sorry to hear that.  It works fine here. _shrug_

Answer (score 1):

A correct (though verbose) way to do this would be to use an XML-aware utility, instead of a generic text processing tools.

E.g. using XSTL transformation with [xsltproc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsltproc):

```
xsltproc - 1.xml <<EOF
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- Identity template (copy input to output) -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>   
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Replace //xyz with its counterpart from 2.xml -->
    <xsl:template match="//xyz">
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('2.xml')//xyz"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
EOF
```

This will correctly replace `//xyz` in `1.xml` with the `//xyz` from 2.xml, regardless of text encoding, formatting, usage of entity references e.t.c.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "
    /<xyz/,/<\/xyz>/c\
        $(
            sed -n '
                /<xyz/{
                    :a;
                    N;
                    /<\/xyz>/! ba;
                    s/\n/\\&/gp;
                    }
                ' 2.xml
        )
    " 1.xml
```

As for me it's much easy to put necessary lines from *2.xml* and substitute (`c`) apropriate line(s) in *1.xml*
Note: `c` command couldn't accept multiline input so we have to add `\` between lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -0777ne '                                # slurp xmls
   $tag2 or ($tag2) = /(<xyz.*<\/xyz>)/s;     # grab tag <xyz> from 2.xml
   @ARGV or print s|<xyz.+?</xyz>|$tag2|srg;  # replace tag <xyz> in 1.xml globally
' 2.xml 1.xml
```